# Mapping Alternate SSL Port in AWS Load Balancing

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently I have this url operational: 
https://leaguemanager.localsportswire.com:8443/test.html

Is there anyway to accomplish the above without having to implicitly state the port in the URL?

The reason I'm doing this is I have two wildcard domains on the same server. One is using port 443, so I am using 8443 for the other.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you use a non-standard port you have to specify it explicitly.
But, using multiple domains (even wildcard) on the same IP address is possible with SNI, newer server and all current browser support this.

Comment: Which server supports this? Windows 2008? 2012?

Comment: windows 2008 probably not, windows 2012 does: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/09/04/server-name-indication-sni-in-iis-8-windows-server-2012.aspx